# Javascript - SyntaxError from import React from 'react'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, syntax-error, atom-editor

Using Atom in Ubuntu 20, I am having the problem of building a simple piece of code:

```
import React from 'react';
console.log('Hello World!')
```

```
import React from 'react';
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using Atom 1.58.0 x64 with `linter-eslint 9.0.0`.

Comment: Try using this one: `const React = require(‘react’);`

Comment: Are you using create-react-app or cusom webpack config? Can you provide your package.json file?

Comment: import is a ES2015 statement while require is a CommonJS import statement.

Comment: @MaximilianDolbaum It does not work.

Comment: @AndrewF This is a simple helloworld.js example.

Comment: @Ale try to use create-react-app  https://create-react-app.dev/